# Are the entities with @Lob fields cacheable in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lob

I use Hibernate and MySQL and I need to store the articles in database. The article entity has a field:

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch=EAGER)
@Column(name="CONTENT")
private byte[] content;
```

Is this entity cacheable in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You can cache your entity using the `@Cacheable` annotation, you're supposed to specify a `<shared-cache-mode>` in the `persistence.xml` (or the equivalent javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode when creating the EntityManagerFactory).

Below, a sample persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="ProjectPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    ...
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      ...
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Yes because you will cache the entire Entity